# JetBrains IDEs - open files with specific extension in a specified window [when split vertically/horizontally]

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, webstorm, text-editor

Looking for a solution (I'm particularly using WebStorm, but this solution should be applied to JetBrains IDEs in general) to specify a set of file extensions and set up a destination window (when split vertically / horizontally), so that whenever you double-click on an HTML file, per say, it opens in the specified window (f.e., window 2, counting from left when split vertically) (not a new IDE window (through Windows Explorer)).

An image to illustrate my intention (`.ts` file should open in Window 1 while `.html` file in Window 2):

[image]

Is there a plugin or anything similar that could help with this? Or should I just use an another IDE / text editor that supports this kind of functionality / flexibility?

Comment: [Files Opened in Associated Applications](https://i.imgur.com/vKDJMpu.png)?

Comment: @CrazyCoder doesn't this manage what files trigger what 3rd party application when opened? this is probably not what i'm looking for. please elaborate.

Comment: Please clarify your question, it states: `(not a new IDE window (through Windows Explorer)).`

Comment: here's an img to illustrate my intention better: https://imgur.com/a/kuRnM
a very basic example - I want files with .js, .ts, etc. extensions to open in Window 1 and files with .html, .scss, etc. exts to open in Window 2. makes sense, @CrazyCoder ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The feature you are asking for is not available in IntelliJ IDEA based products. [There is an open request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-84006), feel free to vote.

Comment: thanks, I'll upvote it. though, it doesn't seem to be a priority of any kind for the Jetbrains team as the request was posted a long time ago. pretty sad.